How can I prevent split() from reordering my data in R?
I have a data frame df and I want to split it by a column called "Verb", and this is what I did:
grouped <- split(df, df$Verb)

The original order of Verb has its very own significance, so it troubles me a lot when split() reorders my data alphabetically. Is there any way such as adding some secret parameter or using an alternative function that would help with this case? I will be doing some counterbalancing work to grouped, so it's important to me that I don't just add a column to keep track of the original order and then resort the entire data.
I tried group_by, mutate() and some other tricks, but none seemed to work. Or I tried them the wrong way.

What is the class of "Verb"? If it is a character, i think split will sort it alphabetically. Try converting it to a factor, and specify levels. Probably then you will get what you expect. I am just guessing because I don't have data to play with. Please give us some toy data to answer your question properly.

@Eva has the right of it -- if order of your string matters, it should be a factor variable, not just string.

split(df, factor(df$Verb, unique(df$Verb)))

Here is a way with order. Create an index i with the original variable's unique values order. Then, rearrange the list output by split using that index.
Example below with the data in jay.sf's answer but with column let renamed to match the question's name Verb.
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(v=1:6, Verb=rep(LETTERS[sample(1:3)], each=2))

i <- df$Verb |> unique() |> order()

s <- split(df, df$Verb)
s[i]
#> $A
#>   v Verb
#> 1 1    A
#> 2 2    A
#> 
#> $C
#>   v Verb
#> 3 3    C
#> 4 4    C
#> 
#> $B
#>   v Verb
#> 5 5    B
#> 6 6    B

Created on 2024-04-06 with reprex v2.1.0

As suggested in the comments you should assign your Verb variable as a factor and define your levels. This will prevent any reordering from split, retaining your specified levels.
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(round(runif(n=50, min=0, max=20), 0), nrow = 10))
df$letters <- sample(LETTERS[1:3], size = 10, replace = TRUE)

print(df)




V1
V2
V3
V4
V5
letters




15
8
14
7
6
C


20
4
10
10
10
C


13
20
17
10
20
A


13
11
8
16
8
C


11
6
1
11
5
A


6
4
5
2
4
C


15
15
7
16
14
C


11
11
3
11
20
B


15
19
10
4
10
C


6
13
16
15
15
C



If you don't split will output tables alphabetically like so:
split(df, df$letters)





V1
V2
V3
V4
V5
letters




3
13
20
17
10
20
A


5
11
6
1
11
5
A







V1
V2
V3
V4
V5
letters




8
11
11
3
11
20
B







V1
V2
V3
V4
V5
letters




1
15
8
14
7
6
C


2
20
4
10
10
10
C


4
13
11
8
16
8
C


6
6
4
5
2
4
C


7
15
15
7
16
14
C


9
15
19
10
4
10
C


10
6
13
16
15
15
C



df$letters <- factor(df$letters, levels = c("C","A","B"))

split(df, df$letters)





V1
V2
V3
V4
V5
letters




1
15
8
14
7
6
C


2
20
4
10
10
10
C


4
13
11
8
16
8
C


6
6
4
5
2
4
C


7
15
15
7
16
14
C


9
15
19
10
4
10
C


10
6
13
16
15
15
C







V1
V2
V3
V4
V5
letters




3
13
20
17
10
20
A


5
11
6
1
11
5
A







V1
V2
V3
V4
V5
letters




8
11
11
3
11
20
B




Actually split(df, factor(df$Verb, unique(df$Verb))) was suggested, not permanently making letters a factor.

If the aim is to restore the original order after reassembly: Note, that there's also unsplit(). As long as you do not change nrow, you will get the original order back.
> df
  v let
1 1   A
2 2   A
3 3   C
4 4   C
5 5   B
6 6   B
> (s <- split(df, df$let))
$A
  v let
1 1   A
2 2   A

$B
  v let
5 5   B
6 6   B

$C
  v let
3 3   C
4 4   C

> unsplit(s, df$let)
  v let
1 1   A
2 2   A
3 3   C
4 4   C
5 5   B
6 6   B

which also works with by
> (s <- by(df, df$let, \(x) transform(x, v=sqrt(v))))
df$let: A
         v let
1 1.000000   A
2 1.414214   A
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
df$let: B
         v let
5 2.236068   B
6 2.449490   B
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
df$let: C
         v let
3 1.732051   C
4 2.000000   C
> unsplit(s, df$let)
         v let
1 1.000000   A
2 1.414214   A
3 1.732051   C
4 2.000000   C
5 2.236068   B
6 2.449490   B


Data:
> set.seed(42)
> df <- data.frame(v=1:6, let=rep(LETTERS[sample(1:3)], each=2))

